# Keyboard shortcut to a Service is not respected when Emacs is open (Emacs takes precedence)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, services, emacs

I defined the keyboard shortcut `Cmd-Ctrl-5` to a Service via System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Services. It should work globally and indeed works well except for when Emacs is open. In that case I see `C-s-5 is undefined` in Emacs which means that Emacs tries to interpret the key combination. How can I give `Cmd-Ctrl-5` "higher" precedence over Emacs, so force macOS to execute the keyboard shortcut (rather than Emacs)?

(A lot of webpages I found discuss the exact opposite, so how to give Emacs precedence over macOS, but interestingly enough I couldn't find the above question asked before. Note that it is *not* the problem that Emacs interprets the key combination [as it says, it's undefined], it just *tries* to interpret it when active, which is what I would like to avoid so that macOS can interpret it. I don't think it matters, but I'm on macOS 10.15.6 [Catalina]).

Comment: I personally quit using **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services** as **macOS** has made it increasing difficult with _keyboard shortcuts_ in general in that area and now use [FastScripts](https://red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) to trigger my **AppleScript** _scripts_. You can assign up tp 10 _keyboard shortcuts_ for free and it's $24.95 USD for unlimited. You should give it a try. Note that I'm not affiliated with the developer of this product, just a satisfied user.

Comment: I have the same question too. If the service you intend to run on emacs was written by you on Applescript, I presume you could use elisp to run that script. https://irreal.org/blog/?p=4865